# How do I find the path to the top of my ROOT source tree?

Tags: root-framework

I'm trying to build ROOT on my MacBook using the terminal; I'm very novice when it comes to programming and downloading these things and I haven't been able to find anything that can explain to me what I need to do. This is what I've done so far: downloaded and unpacked ROOT, installed CMake, and emac. I've just been following the instructions CERN has on their website [Building Root](https://root.cern.ch/building-root).

I made a directory to contain the build, but now I'm on the step which says "Execute the cmake command on the shell replacing path/to/source with the path to the top of your ROOT source tree." However, I have no idea what the path is to the top of my ROOT source tree, nor do I even know what that is to be honest. I'm trying to use ROOT with Xcode because it's really the only compiler I'm familiar with.

How can I find what the path is to the top of my ROOT source tree?

Answer (score 0):

Tree here means the directory tree, so the "directory" or "folder" to which you unpacked root.

So, if your directory structure looks like this:

```
Downloads
├── PlaneTicket
├── oldThings
│   ├── Pictures
│   ├── Movies
│   ├── PDF-Documents
├── backup
│   ├── data
│   └── dataset
├── backup2
│   ├── data
│   └── dataset
├── build   (<- I assume your build directory is there)
├── ROOT
│   ├── bindings
│   │   ├── doc
│   │   ├── pyroot
│   │   ├── r
│   │   └── ruby
│   ├── build
│   │   ├── misc
│   │   ├── package
│   │   ├── rmkdepend
│   │   ├── unix
│   │   └── win
│   ├── cmake
│   │   ├── modules
│   │   ├── patches
│   │   └── scripts
│   ├── config
│   ├── core
│   │   ...
│   ├── doc
│   │   ...
│   ├── documentation
│   │   ...
│   ...
└── very_old_files
```

Then your cmake commands should looks like this

```
cmake ../ROOT
```

Comment: Yes, I've been doing cmake commands and they have looked like that. The site says to replace the "path/to/source" of $ cmake path/to/source with the top of the ROOT source tree, but I'm confused as to what I replaced it with. Do I replace it with the name of the directory I just built (per instructions)?

Comment: Yes. (well, I might be more confusing than helping now: it should be either an absolute path or a relative path from your build directory to the directory with the source code. So you cannot just do `cmake ROOT` if the directory with the source code and your build directory are in two completely different places on your harddisk)

Answer (score 0):

If you've followed CERN's instructions that far, you can simply use the command 'dir' or 'ls' and the path to source will print to screen. Type 'cmake', and then copy/paste that in front of it to build ROOT.

Comment: @PradeepBanavara Whichever command you can use to find the directory you're currently in should be sufficient